# Converting large number into a usable string in PHP

Tags: php

I am getting data from an API and it includes a long number, for example: `7979798798798798798798797987`. I need to put this number into a URL so the variable doesn't need to be a number but I do need it to stay intact precisely. At the moment PHP is automatically converting the large number into scientific notation. I have tried all these things like sprintf and trying to cast it as a string but it's not working for me.

Here's a demo:

```
$myvar = 7979798798798798798798797987; //can't change this as this is from api

echo $myvar; // needs to print out 7979798798798798798798797987
```

Comment: "getting data from an API" and assigning a literal to a PHP variable are two different things. If you really retrieve it somewhere, it's mostly likely serialized in string form. Why not keep it that way?

Comment: Hi Mario, thanks for your comment. What you are saying is what I thought. When I echo out the value it echos out as serialized string. However a client who is using my code is saying it is rendering as scientific notation.

Comment: If it's transferred via JSON, it might very well end up auto-converted to a float (newer PHP versions offer `JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING` to keep long ints).

Comment: $destinationUrl = "http://clientwebsite.com/".$data['Key'];

echo $destinationUrl; //echos out http://clientwebsite.com/7.9797987988E+27

Comment: yes it is being transferred via JSON, I will try this out! Thank you so much

Comment: where is your json response???

Comment: represent this large number in string format `$myvar = '7979798798798798798798797987';` and put this string in url

Answer (score 0):

If PHP encounters a number beyond the bounds of the integer type, it will be interpreted as a float instead (which is what you have) of int but float have a limited precision of around 14 digits.

If the number is less than 14 digits, you can use `sprintf('%0.0f',$number)`;

In your case, you would need to work from your source data (json), as there is no way you can produce an exact representation of that number from its current form (float).

you can use the `JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING` options in json_decode

Sample Test Code

```
<?php
$json = '{"number":7979798798798798798798797987, "data":"some other data"}';
$output=json_decode($json, false, 512, JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING);
echo $output->number; \\output 7979798798798798798798797987
?>
```